# Finding multiple elements

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, integration

I can't seem to figure out the best way to find multiple elements on a page.

It always finds one but what if I'm testing to see how many particular elements are present after some kind of action?

```
findElement() // always returns 1 element
findElements(By.className('someClass')) // always returns 1 element
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In case someone looks for this in the future, I got it to work:

```
findElements(By.className("someclass")).then(function(elements_arr){ 
    console.log(elements_arr.length);
});
```

According to their source code, findElements returns a promise

[Webdriverjs API](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebElement.html#findElements)