# Counting elements with the same selector in webdriver.io

Tags: selenium, webdriver, mocha.js, chai

I am using [webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io/) with chai and mocha for testing.

In one of my tests I need to count how many elements with the same CSS class are in the page. None of the [webdriver.io API](http://webdriver.io/docs.html) seems to return an array.

How can it be achieved?

Comment: This link should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677516/webdriverjs-finding-multiple-elements

Comment: @Richard: well, that link is unfortunately about webdriverjs, not webdriver.io.

For reference: https://github.com/camme/webdriverjs#disclaimer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
client.elements('.myElements', function(err,res) {
    console.log('element count: ',res.value.length);
});
```

Explanation: with `elements` you fetch all elements according given selector. It returns an array of webdriver elements which represents the amount of existing elements on the page.

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed work.
Is there a reason for which the .elements() method is not documented currently on the website (I indeed found a mention to it on Github)?

Answer (score 9):

For version 4 of webdriver.io, this is the way

```
client.elements('.selector').then(function (elems) {
    console.log(elems.value.length);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

For version 7.13.2 of webdriver.io, you can try this

```
 const count = await $$('selector').length
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can write to a variable and later use it

```
let smth = browser.elements('selector').value.length;
```