# get text of all elements with the same selector in webdriver.io

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I am using webdriver.io

In one of my tests I need to get the text for all the elements with the same xpath that are in the page. How can I achieve this?

I know how to find the length of elements using client.elements() but not able to get the text. referred the link for this [Counting elements with the same selector in webdriver.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274482/counting-elements-with-the-same-selector-in-webdriver-io/23282353)

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below.

```
const textArray = browser.$$('.myElements').map(elem => elem.getText());
```